# Chrome Extension callback when restarted or shut down

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is there a chrome extension callback to detect when an extension is restarted or the browser is closed?

I see [`chrome.runtime.onSuspend`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onSuspend) but can not get that to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a chrome extension callback to detect when an extension is restarted

Yes, [`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onStartup) will fire when the extension is loaded *for any reason,* e.g. the browser is started or the extension is restarted.

> or the browser is closed?

No, you don't get any event in this case. Chrome won't wait for extensions if the last window of the browser is requested to close.

`chrome.runtime.onSuspend` is only for the non-persistent event pages unloading while the browser continues to run.